# Taking unknown numbers count to array from user

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, input

How can I get some numbers from a user and place them into an array, without knowing how many numbers will he give? And then, how can I (for example) take the last 5 numbers from that array?

Comment: Use std::vector.

Comment: if you insist on using arrays than you would need to use pointers to allocated heap, watch the size of it and if next element does not fit, you would need to reallocate the array with the new size and copy elements from old location to the new one. It is more elegant to use vectors as manni66 suggested. Unless you are in 'c'.

Comment: @manni66: The comments section is not for answers. That's what the answer section is for. Thanks.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I did not answer the question.

Comment: @manni66: "How do I do <X>?" "Use a vector." That is suggesting a solution to the problem. To do so properly, write an answer.... or don't. But the comments section is for (a) requesting clarification, (b) critiquing and (c) having fights. Cheers!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition you like (c)?

Comment: @manni66: Just trying to help you use Stack Exchange effectively. No need to try start a fight (which is what you just did there with your little personal attack)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as a container. A simple use-case that accepts the user input and constructs a new vector containing the last 5 elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vec;
    int temp;
    char c = 'y';
    while (std::cin && c == 'y'){
        std::cout << "Enter number: ";
        std::cin >> temp;
        vec.push_back(temp);
        std::cout << "Continue entering? y / n: ";
        std::cin >> c;
    }
    // get the last 5 elements:
    if (vec.size() >= 5){
        std::vector<int> vec5(vec.rbegin(), vec.rbegin() + 5);
        for (auto el : vec5){
            std::cout << el << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't check for error flags on the input stream. You're also doing some naughty stuff at the end - at least check size >= 5 first (and `rbegin()` might look more pleasing). Finally, don't `endl` when you don't have to.

Comment: `while (std::cin && c == 'y')` will be fine